# How to Implement Facebook like Image Upload

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on an app that has provision for uploading images to server with a comment, but my worry is that image upload method is taking sometime, I employed AsyncTasking, I was thinking of a method that works more like Facebook does,when upload starts, the user can leave the activity yet the upload still continues in background, can anyone help me on how I can do that?

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new PostComment().execute();
  //  new UploadFileToServer().execute();

}

class PostComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddComment.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Posting Isampo...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String post_title = title.getText().toString();
        String post_message = message.getText().toString();
        String post_condition = condition.getText().toString();
        String post_make = make.getText().toString();
        String post_method_of_sell= samposell.getText().toString();
        String post_post_identifier = generated;
        generatedgone = generated;

        //We need to change this:
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AddComment.this);
        String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", post_title));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("make", post_make));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("condition", post_condition));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("purchase_method", post_method_of_sell));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", post_message));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_tag",post_post_identifier));


            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script 
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    POST_COMMENT_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Post post attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("post Added!", json.toString());
               // finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("post Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(AddComment.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}




public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}



 /**
 * Checking device has camera hardware or not
 * */
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}



/**
 * Launching camera app to capture image
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Launching camera app to record video
 */



/**
 * Launching camera app to record video
 */
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
    // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}


/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // successfully captured the image
            // launching upload activity
            launchUploadActivity(true);


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // video successfully recorded
            // launching upload activity
            launchUploadActivity(false);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user cancelled recording
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        } else {
            // failed to record video
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }


    //Loading Image From Gallery
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            // Set the Image in ImageView
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgPath));


            //setting Image View
            if (imgView != null & imgView.getDrawable() != null) {
                imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

                imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            File f = new File(imgPath);
            imagepath = imgPath;
            filename = f.getName();

            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
     //important ---> params.put("filename", fileName);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
    // boo
    // lean flag to identify the media type, image or video

    if(fileUri.getPath() !=null & isImage==true) {

        filePath = fileUri.getPath();

        if (filePath != null) {
            // Displaying the image or video on the screen
            previewMedia(isImage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

// Displaying captured image/video on the screen

private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
    // Checking whether captured media is image or video
    if (isImage) {
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
        // start playing
        videoPreview.start();
    }
}



    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Error", "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

/***Unique Image and post Tags***/
public  void randInt() {

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    int Random = rand.nextInt((1000001 - 1) + 1) +1;

 generated = Integer.toString(Random);


}



//stats uploading
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressbar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressbar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        percentagetxt.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);


            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));


            //Adding image_identifier
            entity.addPart("image_identifier", new StringBody(generatedgone.toString()));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("RESPONSE", "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

/*** Method to show alert dialog
 **/
private void showAlert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: You should really be showing some code to show what you have tried

Comment: Seems the answer here is to use a service: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html or is your question more specific than that?